# Reuse a method on a struct

Tags: go

I have a method that takes a URL to a yaml file and unmarshals it into a struct. There's nothing unique about it so I'd like to use it on another struct.

```
type SWConfig struct {
    Name      string `yaml:"name"`
    Version   string `yaml:"version"`
    BuildType string `yaml:"buildType"`
}

func (c *SWConfig) getConfiguration(url string) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("ERROR: GET request failed: %s\n", err.Error())
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        log.Fatalf("ERROR: %v:  %s\n", resp.Status, url)
    }
    source, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("ERROR: could not read response: %s\n", err.Error())
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(source, c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("ERROR: could not read YAML: %s\n", err.Error())
    }
}

var swConfig SWConfig
swConfig.getConfiguration(swURL)
fmt.Println(swConfig.Name)
```

The other struct would have different fields, but again that shouldn't matter for this method. Is it possible to reuse this method or do I need to convert it to a function?

Comment: "I'd like to use it on another struct" --- another struct with identical structure? `getConfiguration(url string, s interface{}) error` may be then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this utility function. It works with a pointer to any type.

```
// fetchYAML unmarshals the YAML document at url to the value 
// pointed to by v.
func fetchYAML(url string, v interface{}) error {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return fmt.Errorf("bad status: %v:  %s\n", resp.Status, url)
    }
    source, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(source, v)
    return err
}
```

Call it like this:

```
func (c *SWConfig) getConfiguration(url string) {
    if err := fetchYAML(url, c); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("ERROR: get value failed: %s\n", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add v needs to be passed as pointer ; Also Question asks for yaml and you used json; yaml.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target) is shorter an much cleaner

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava  I fixed the first two issues. I left the yaml call as is because we don't know if the yaml package used by OP has a NewDecoder function.